# sencha touch 2 list 100% height

Tags: sencha-touch-2

2 panels:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'message list',
            flex: 1,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    itemTpl: '{title}',
                    data: [
                        { title: 'Item 1' },
                        { title: 'Item 2' },
                        { title: 'Item 3' },
                        { title: 'Item 4' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'message preview',
            flex: 3
        }
    ]
});
```

There is no height attribute specified in first panels list object, so it is not available for display. How can i set 100% height in xtype: 'list' ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to give the lists **container** a layout so it knows to stretch its children (the list).

```
layout: 'fit'
```

Using fit will tell your panel to make all children (only the list in your case) to stretch to the size of your panel.

[Example of this on Sencha Fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#MfLkR).

[And here is a great guide on all the available layouts in Sencha Touch 2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/layouts).

Comment: Sencha docs mention this ... "Please note that if you add more than one item into a container with a fit layout, only the first item will be visible."

Comment: The point is it will not work as expected -- the one visible item will expand to fit the space -- not the container expanding to fit all the child items.

Comment: Correct, however in this case the container only has **one** child, a *list*, which we want to stretch to the size of the container. So **fit** is the appropriate layout.